# How do I find the adverbs in my writing?

Tags: adverbs

I have to find adverbs in my writing and other students' writing, but I get confused about how to accurately identify just what is the adverb. I have capitalized a piece of writing to show what I think, but I am not optimistic.

> The radiator gurgled as he returned to the letter on his desk. "Day of
>   rest; if only…" he murmured. MERCIFULLY not a difficult achievement,
>   the sergeant's transfer had been approved and he started 'out west' in
>   a fortnight. Excluding promotion, few officers volunteered for
>   ANYWHERE too far from the coast, and the superintendent, WHILE
>   grateful he COULD deploy such a solid officer, took the time to call
>   FIRST and confirm the sergeant's intentions.

Comment: What is your reasoning for marking *while* and *could* as adverbs?

Comment: Note that in a sentence like "Mercifully, it was not difficult", "mercifully" is not functioning as an adverb. The speaker is using the word to make a comment on the entire clause which follows.

Comment: *Adverb* is not a function, it's a category.  So although *mercifully* is an adverb in your example, this doesn't tell you what its function is.

Answer (score 2):

An adverb describes a verb. It may be easiest to find verbs first, and then identify any adverbs that describe them. Remember that a verb is a word that conveys action or a state of existence.

Verbs:

- He ***stood*** silently.
- The wind ***blew*** forcefully.
- Impatiently, she ***asked*** again.
- Filled with sorrow, she ***cried***.

Now, the adverbs:

- He stood ***silently***. *(Because silently describes how he stood.)*
- The wind blew ***forcefully***. *(Forcefully is how the wind blew.)*
- ***Impatiently***, she asked again. *(Impatiently is the manner in which she asked.)*
- Filled with sorrow, she cried. *(There are no adverbs in this sentence. Sorrow is a noun here. It would be an adverb if instead it were "Sorrowfully, she cried.")*

In your text, "mercifully" is an adjective, describing the achievement. It is both "not difficult" and "merciful" (because it is not difficult).

If you read the text carefully, you'll note that there are **no** words that describe actions or states of being.

**Edit:**

As pointed out by @Tyler, the words "too far" are adverbs for "volunteered." In this case, they're not describing how the action was performed, but rather, qualifying *whether* the action was performed (the criteria for it). Easy to miss!

Comment: What is the relationship between “too far...” and “volunteered”? That seemed potentially adverbial to me.

Comment: You're right! "Too" and "far" are both adverbs and in this case they're modifying "volunteered." At first glance (I missed it) they seemed like adjectives related to the "coast." I'll make an edit accordingly. Good catch.

Comment: You can't identify verbs by semantic tests; a noun can convey an action or a state of being.  And adverbs have lots of uses besides modifying verbs in both traditional and modern grammar--though considerably more in traditional grammar, since the rule used to be "If you don't know what it is, call it an adverb".  To begin with, an adverb can modify not only a verb, but also an adjective (*very smart*) or another adverb (*surprisingly quickly*).  Adverbs can also appear as supplements rather than modifiers (an example from CGEL, p.57: ***Unhappily***, *the letter arrived too late.*).

Comment: @snailboat How can a noun convey an action and still be a noun? For example adding -ing to the noun "smoke" makes it a verb "smoking."

Comment: *A siege* denotes an action, but it's a noun phrase.  Anyway, you can't add *-ing* to the noun *smoke*.  You can add *-ing* to the verb *smoke*, and that's exactly the sort of **syntactic** test you can use to determine whether something is a verb.  Further reading [here](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=282) and [here](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/000932.html).